# Lifecycle management policy not working on Azure Data Lake Gen 2

Tags: azure, lifecycle, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2, retention

Im trying to test the lifecycle management policy feature in the Azure Data Lake Gen 2, for that i created a rule indicating to move the files within a directory inside the container to the cool tier after one day of modification. The rule isnt working, it doesnt move the files inside tje directory to the cool tier after the day, does someone know how to set the lifecycle management policy dor an especific directory inside de data lake in order to apply the rule to all the files inside?

I specified the path as follows: datalaketest/bronze/testfile/

Comment: One possible reason is that the rule may take a few hours to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

> I created a new policy, why do the actions not run immediately?

The platform runs the lifecycle policy once a day. Once you configure a policy, it can take up to 24 hours for some actions to run for the first time.

> If I update an existing policy, how long does it take for the actions to run?

The updated policy takes up to 24 hours to go into effect. Once the policy is in effect, it could take up to 24 hours for the actions to run. Therefore, the policy actions may take up to 48 hours to complete.

**Reference:** [Azure Blob Storage - lifecycle management policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#add-or-remove-a-policy)

Comment: If it is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.